# Visualforce Order of Execution for an apex:dynamiccomponent within an apex:component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, order-of-execution

I have a Visualforce component that contains an apex:dynamiccomponent to render various controls based on a configured Custom Metadata type.

editMode Component:

```
<apex:component controller="componentController">
    <apex:attribute name="value" type="String" description="Sample component." assignTo="{!selectedValue}"/>
    <p>
    Value = {!value}<br/>
    selectedValue = {!selectedValue}<br/>
    </p>

    <apex:dynamiccomponent componentvalue="{!dynamicControls}" />

</apex:component>
```

editMode Component Controller:

```
public class componentController {
    public String selectedValue {
        get {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController.selectedValue get: ' + selectedValue);
            return selectedValue;
        }
        set {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController.selectedValue set: ' + value);
            selectedValue = value;
        }
    }

    public componentController() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController constructor called.');
    }

    public Component.Apex.PageBlockSection getDynamicControls() {

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController.getDynamicControls() called.');

        Component.Apex.PageBlockSection pbSection = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSection();
    pbSection.title='Custom Controls';
    pbSection.showHeader = true;
    pbSection.columns = 2;

        Component.Apex.OutputText test = new Component.Apex.OutputText(value='Dyanmic Component selectedValue:' + selectedValue);
        pbSection.childComponents.add(test);

        return pbSection;
    }
}
```

Visualforce page containing the component:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:messages />
    <apex:pageBlock title="Component page block">
        <c:editMode value="foo"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This results in the following. Note how the dynamic OutputText component saw the selectedValue as null but the direct bind got the attribute value.

[image]

Debug log extract:

> 6 14:12:49.000    0.016156909 USER_DEBUG  [14]    DEBUG   componentController constructor called.
>   7   14:12:49.000    0.016369249 USER_DEBUG  [19]    DEBUG   componentController.getDynamicControls() called.
>   8   14:12:49.000    0.017155422 USER_DEBUG  [4] DEBUG   componentController.selectedValue get: null
>   9   14:12:49.000    0.018336522 USER_DEBUG  [8] DEBUG   componentController.selectedValue set: Foo
>   10  14:12:49.000    0.102206825 USER_DEBUG  [8] DEBUG   componentController.selectedValue set: Foo
>   11  14:12:49.000    0.10254756  USER_DEBUG  [4] DEBUG   componentController.selectedValue get: Foo

I've had a similar issue before in [Unexpected Visualforce Order of Execution with component attributes on Get Request](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/117374/102). That was slightly different as it dealt with the order in which the constructors were called.

Answer (score 3):

The debug log shows the issue. The binding expression on the `componentController` for the `apex:dynamiccomponent` is called after the constructor and before the values from the attributes are assigned.

To work around this issue, the dynamic components need to use [the expressions property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm?search_text=expressions) to define expression statements that will dynamically bind the property values.

E.g.

modified editMode Component Controller:

```
public class componentController {
    public String selectedValue {
        get {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController.selectedValue get: ' + selectedValue);
            return selectedValue;
        }
        set {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController.selectedValue set: ' + value);
            selectedValue = value;
        }
    }

    public componentController() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController constructor called.');
    }

    public Component.Apex.PageBlockSection getDynamicControls() {

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.Debug, 'componentController.getDynamicControls() called.');

        Component.Apex.PageBlockSection pbSection = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSection();
        pbSection.title='Custom Controls';
        pbSection.showHeader = true;
        pbSection.columns = 2;

        Component.Apex.OutputText test = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
        // Modified here to use expressions to bind to the property set by an attribute
        test.expressions.value = '{!selectedValue} Test';
        pbSection.childComponents.add(test);

        return pbSection;
    }
}
```

Which gives:

[image]