# Rerender causes getter to get called even when it should not

Tags: visualforce, controller, actionfunction, actionregion

Can anyone explain to me why my list is getting re-populated even when it shouldn't? 
As you can see in the code, the ActionFunction is inside an ActionRegion and only reRenders an outputPanel with Id "nothing". 
In the controller "getAccounts()" keeps getting called after the DML. This is where it gets confusing because to my understanding if I don't reRender the Page, Form or the OutputPanel holding the table, it shouldn't get called.

for now, my work around is using a variable Reload to control when the list gets populated. Otherwise, imagine displaying 1000 rows and doing some insert or update, since the list get's re-populated no matter what, it takes a long time to process any DML.

I will really appreciate any explanation on this problem.

Page

```
 <apex:page>
   <apex:form>
       <apex:outputPanel id="nothing"></apex:outputPanel>
          <apex:actionRegion >
             <apex:actionFunction action="{!DoSomething}" name="DoSomething" reRender="nothing'>
                    <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedAccId}" name="SelectedAccId" value=""/>
             </apex:actionFunction>
        </apex:actionRegion> 

        <apex:outputPanel id="MyAccounts" layout="block" >
            <table id="TheTable" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>  
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Accounts}" var="a">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span onclick="DoSomething('{!a.AccountId}');" >{!a.AccountId}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>{!a.AccountName}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class ControllerBeta{ 
public transient Id SelectedAccId {get;set;}
public void DoSomething(){
  //do something with the selected Id
  Product__c p = [SELECT Id FROM Product__c WHERE Account__c = :SelectedAccId];
  //debug('DoSomething'); 
}

private transient List<TheAccount> Accounts;
public List<TheAccount> getAccounts(){
    //if(Accounts == null && Reload){ work around
    if(Accounts == null){
        //debug('getAccounts');
        Accounts = new List<TheAccount>();
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 5]){
            Accounts.add(new TheAccount(a.Id, a.Name));
        }
    }
    return Accounts;
}

public class TheAccount{
    public Id AccountId { get; set; }
    public String AccountName { get; set; }
    public TheAccount(Id accId, String accName){
        AccountId = accId;
        AccountName = accName;  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this might help you - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69279/order-of-execution-for-visualforce-page-get-requests?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This might not be an answer.... but why don't you try Javascript Remoting instead?

Comment: Sebastian,  thank you for suggesting that!  but I  still want to understand what is causing the reRender problem. It just makes no sense to me.

Comment: I believe it is because your Accounts variable is transient which means it is not included in the view state. When your DoSomething action is called, you are sending the request to the server along with the view state. In your DoSomething method, you are finding the account to update from the Accounts list variable. However, since that list isn't included in the view state it is null. This causes your getter to fire again.

Comment: Try modifying the call to the action function to prevent the page rerendering. 
`<span onclick="DoSomething('{!a.AccountId}');return false;" >`.

Comment: Zach Field, thank you for your response! I just updated the script so it's clear that I am not trying to manipulate the AccountList, therefore it should not get it again.

Comment: Daniel,  thank you for your response! I tried adding "return false" but still doing the same.

Comment: In case someone is interested about this, any type of repeater will cause the getter to get called. I assume this is a bug